# inserting a date into database with JSONParser module

Tags: feeds

i have a json file

`{
  "student":[{"firstname":"bharath","marks":"80","dateone":"13/09/2014 06:07:08","datetwo":"18/12/2016 09:08:05"},
        {"firstname":"purna","marks":"70","dateone":"17/03/2012 06:07:08","datetwo":"20/04/2017 09:08:05"},
        {"firstname":"ramesh","marks":"90","dateone":"23/11/2010 06:07:08","datetwo":"14/08/2009 09:08:05"}]
}`

i'm mapping the json parser as

`parser0 -> field_firstname`
`parser1 -> field_marks`
`parser2 -> field_dateone`
`parser3 -> field_datetwo`

[image]

i'm able to get firstname and marks in database which are of type varchar but dateone and datetwo are not entered in database which are of datetime type.

Can Anyone please help !!!

Thanks in advance !